# Rails.cache.clear returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have this setup 
`config.cache_store = :redis_store, ENV['REDIS_CACHE_URL']`

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> set random_key 1
OK
```

Now I go to the console and do `Rails.cache.clear` which returns nil

And I am still able to access the key `random_key` in the redis-cli. It did not clear the cache.

I could not read what `Rails.cache` returns here too `ruby/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails.rb`

**Is Rails.cache.clear is supposed to return true?**

Can someone please help me out if my understanding is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`redis-cache` stores data under a particular namespace.

For example, if you've configured `redis-store` according to [Documentation](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails#usage), then cache keys will be stored under `cache` namespace. That means, that when you `Rails.cache.write("random_key", "key")` a key `cache:random_key` will appear in the Redis. Therefore, when you `Rails.cache.clear`, only keys under `cache` namespace will be deleted.

Hence, if you manually create `random_key` in Redis, `Rails.cache.clear` won't remove it. But if you manually create `cache:random_key`, it will.

Comment: Thanks that explains in great detail :)

Comment: If you are using redis store you can also pass the namespace to be cleared Rails.cache.clear(namespace: :yournamespace)

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when using `Rails.cache.clear` it will invalidate all the keys for the application [(source)](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html#method-i-clear)

[~Not sure if this is the best place for this answer~]

[This helpful article](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/rails-adds-support-for-recyclable-cache-keys) was a great way for me to understand caching when changing versions of Rails from 5.1+ to Rails 6.1+.  The article talks about options for generating a cache key with or without versioning.

In the instance of my application, versioning was needed but not turned on when upgraded to Rails 6.1:

```
#in application.rb
config.active_record.collection_cache_versioning = true
```

Then within the application code where `object.cache_key` is called, I had to change it to `object.cache_key_with_version` [(source)](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Integration.html)